# OrientDB: Weird behaviour of limit

Tags: orientdb

Hello everybody (again),

I'm witnessing a weird behaviour of OrientDB when I'm using the `LIMIT` keyword together with `in()` and `expand()`:

the query

```
select expand(in()) from Employee
```

returns `0 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.0 sec(s).`, while the query

```
select expand(in()) from Employee limit 1000
```

returns `52 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.062 sec(s).`

Does anybody know what's happening?
Unfortunately I cannot share the data I'm using, however, my Employee class has > 15k instances of which only ~1400 have an in-edge.

Comment: Which version of OrientDB?

Comment: The version is OrientDB 2.1.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that you are running query from studio. 
By default is limit 20 and  That could means that in the first 20 employees you do not have in() relationships.

So the result set is empty.
But i think it is a bug and has been fixed recently.
https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/5153